# Search next occurrence of pattern before and after a previously different matched pattern and extract everything in between to a different file

Tags: text-processing, logs

I have a huge log file (tens of gigs) on a server. It is simply too large to download in a reasonable amount of time. However, I am actually only interested in a relatively small subset of lines. The log file has an xml-like structure. There are a lot of `<log>...</log>` entries in which one of them there is a specific pattern I am looking for, lets say `"Failure"` (when `grep` for `"Failure"` I only have 1 match):

```
<log>...</log>
<log>...</log>

....

<log>  (*1*)
      ...
      ... "Failure" ...
      ... 
</log> (*2*)

....

<log>...</log>
<log>...</log>
```

My idea is to search for the immediate previous and next occurrence of `<log>` `(*1*)` and `</log>` `(*2*)` before and after the line containing `"Failure"`, respectively. Afterwards I want to copy those lines to a separate file which I can then easily download.

Pseudo-code summary:

```
failure_line = find pattern "Failure" in log file
start_line = find immediate previous occurrence of <log> before the line failure_line
finish_line = find immediate next occurrence of </log> after the line failure_line
copy all lines from start_line until finish_line to a new file
```

Can this somehow be achieved with a `bash` script without a big overhead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that standard text-processing tools like `sed`, `perl` or `awk` are not meant for XML parsing. If you can rely on some things like not more than one `<log>...</log>` pair in one line, you could do it this way with `sed`:

```
sed '/<log>.*<\/log>/{/Failure/p;d;};/<log>/,/<\/log>/H;/<log>/h;/<\/log>/!d;x;/Failure/!d' your.log
```

- '/.*</log>/' maches lines with a complete tag. Those need to be handled seperately: `/Failure/p` prints them if they contain `Failure`, `d` stops further processing.
- Now `/<log>/,/<\/log>/` selects lines between the opeing `<log>` and the closing `</log>` and appends them to the hold space (the clipboard of `sed`) with `H`
- `/<log>/h` initializes the hold space for any new `log` sequence
- `/<\/log>/!d` stops processing for all lines but those with closing `</log>`
- So the following is executed only for closing logs: `x` exchanges the hold and pattern space, so we have everything in the pattern space that was collected since the last `<log>` line. `d`elete it if it doesn't contain `Failure`, otherwise it gets printed by default at the end of the script

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! How could I change the query if I wanted to copy from the previous <log> tag until the end of the file?

Comment: You mean it could be that the last closing tag is missing?

Comment: Exactly and also just in general to copy other log tags that are following the one of interest.